# Can't read empty cell from excel file

Tags: c#, excel

There is an excel file like this:

```
1  | AAAA | val1_1
2  |      | val1_2
3  | EEEE | val2_1
4  |      | val2_2
5  |      | val2_3
6  | CCCC | val3_1
```

There is a code:

```
Excel.Application xclApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks xclWorkbooks;
Excel.Workbook xclWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet xclWorksheet;
Excel.Range xclRange;

xclWorkbooks = xclApp.Workbooks;
string path = "Some path";
xclWorkbook = xclWorkbooks.Open(path);
xclWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xclWorkbook.Worksheet.get_Item(1);
range = xclWorksheet.UsedRange;

string column1Value = "";
string column2Value = "";
for(int i=1; i<=range.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    column1Value = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range).Value);
    column2Value = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[i, 2] as Excel.Range).Value);
}
```

1 itteration:
`column1Value = 1; column2Value = AAAA`

2 itteration:
`column1Value = 2; column2Value = EEEE`

3 ittertaion:
`column1Value = 3; column2Value = CCCC`

Why code doesn't get empty value in second itteration in second row and second column? In the same way 4 and 5 rows.

Comment: based on your code there isn't a reason why it's doing that - are you sure that's how your data is laid out and that you've got the right sheet?

Comment: How is `UserRange` defined in the worksheet? If you just select the cells directly, do you get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested in knowing what happens if you read in the entire block of cells in one go:

```
xclWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xclWorkbook.Worksheet.get_Item(1);

//  Try adding the following lines...  what happens ?
Range entireWorksheet = xclWorksheet.Range["A1", "Z99999"];  
object[,] values = (object[,])entireWorksheet.Value2;

int numberOfRows = arr.GetUpperBound(0);
int numberOfColumns = arr.GetUpperBound(1);
```

This is also a much more efficient method of reading in the data from an Excel Worksheet, rather than reading in the data, cell by cell.

We use code like this in some of our C# Excel Addin apps to cache all the data from an Excel worksheet.

Comment: This is generally the best way to work with a range in _any_ language

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Range` (from exact cell to exact cell number) instead of `UsedRange`.